# How can I Iterate Through Fields in a SQL Server Database Table A, Finding Common Values in Other Tables?

Tags: sql, database

Say we have a database with a bunch of tables. Let's say that we have a table called A. How can I iterate through each field in A where for each iteration, we check to see if any other table in the database has a field that has at least one value in common with the field in A that is currently being iterated on. Then, we need to return a result that shows the field in A being iterated on, the table in the database that has a value in common with the field in A and the name of that field in the other table. I'm doing this with MS SQL Server.

```
DECLARE @TableName NVARCHAR(255) = 'A';

DECLARE @ColumnName NVARCHAR(255);
DECLARE column_cursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT COLUMN_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = @TableName;

CREATE TABLE #CommonValues (TableAField NVARCHAR(255), TableB NVARCHAR(255), CommonFieldInA NVARCHAR(255), CommonFieldInB NVARCHAR(255));

OPEN column_cursor;
FETCH NEXT FROM column_cursor INTO @ColumnName;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    DECLARE @DynamicSQL NVARCHAR(MAX);
    SET @DynamicSQL = N'INSERT INTO #CommonValues (TableAField, TableB, CommonFieldInA, CommonFieldInB)
                      SELECT ''' + @ColumnName + ''', T.TABLE_NAME, ''' + @ColumnName + ''', C.COLUMN_NAME
                      FROM ' + @TableName + ' AS A
                      INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES AS T
                      ON T.TABLE_NAME <> ''' + @TableName + '''
                      INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS AS C
                      ON C.TABLE_NAME = T.TABLE_NAME
                      AND C.COLUMN_NAME = ''' + @ColumnName + '''
                      WHERE EXISTS (
                          SELECT 1
                          FROM ' + @TableName + ' AS B
                          WHERE A.' + @ColumnName + ' = B.' + @ColumnName + ')';

    EXEC sp_executesql @DynamicSQL;

    FETCH NEXT FROM column_cursor INTO @ColumnName;
END

CLOSE column_cursor;
DEALLOCATE column_cursor;

SELECT * FROM #CommonValues;

DROP TABLE #CommonValues;
```

Comment: This sounds like a very odd situation. Can you share the reason behind needing this? There's almost certainly a simpler solution, or a serious schema design error that should be addressed.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn The main project is the find relationships between tables (beyond the Primary and Foreign Key relationships). I'm trying to explore different strategies to do this, and this just happened to be one of the strategies we discussed. I have a lot of tables that have two different field names for the same data that is being represented. For example, table A might have a field called f and table B might have a field called g. A and B have a relationship between each other if f and g represent the same data (or similar format of data).

Comment: You may find [this article](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/auto-suggesting-foreign-keys-and-data-model-archaeology) useful.

Comment: While you could definitely write a cursor to iterate through every value in every field and return every other record/field containing the same value, one of the challenges you'll face is incompatible types for comparison - many different types cannot be implicitly (or even explicitly) converted, so you'd need to either narrow your search to only fields with matching types, or create some matrix of which types can be converted and tested for equivalence I guess.

Comment: As @JoelCoehoorn says though, this seems like an odd approach for sure and prone to lots of false positives. For example, every single `bit` field in the DB will be "matched" to every other `bit` field, and probably many other fields like `int` for example, so you'll end up with huge amounts of false positives to comb through.

Comment: @3N1GM4 Thank you for your response! For now, I don't actually mind if I pick up a lot of false positives. If you have any other suggestions for finding these relationships, please do let me know. Can you help me out with the script? Thanks!